# How to get parameter value from StackTrace

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, stack-trace

From within a method call I need to "jump" three layers up the stack and retrieve the type and value of the parameters passed to that method.
Getting the parameter type is easy but I couldn't find a way to get the value passed to a certain method on the stack.

```
var st = new StackTrace();
var frames = st.GetFrames();
var methodParameters = frame[2].GetMethod().GetParameters;
// get each parameter value
```

Note: using `StackTrace`is not mandatory.

Is there a wayto find a value of a parameter passed to a method during runtime?

Comment: I just ran into this and I couldn't find a good way to get values.  I would up creating a framework to store the values on the entry point to my application.

Comment: I could be asking for the impossible - It seems that it's not possible to get the called method's values from the stacktrace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think there is a method unless you develop your own system for storing the values.

The reflection namespace represents *static* data about an assembly, and you would need to retrieve values at runtime.

I found [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) mentioned in MSDN forums, but I have never tried it.