# Get variable value by name

Tags: vb.net, reflection, system.reflection

Does anyone know of any way to dynamically get the value of a parameter by name? I'm trying to create a function that will dynamically pass on its parameters. I'm using Reflection to get the name of the parameter but can't seem to figure out how to get the value that was passed to the function.

Example:

```
Imports System.Reflection

Console.WriteLine(Test("Xyzzy"))
' Should print: Xyzzy

Function Test(ByVal x as String)
  Return GetValueByName(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.GetParameters(0).Name))
End Function
```

Comment: Could you give a better example and maybe the goal behind it? In this case I would say: return the value of x

Comment: It is currently not possible in .NET. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867482/c-sharp-getting-value-of-parms-using-reflection)

Comment: If this code is going *inside* the same method that you wish to examine, then surely it doesn't need to be dynamic? As the author of the method you already know all the parameters.

Comment: I'm going to be creating many functions that will take their parameters and call a routine in another class. I was just looking for a way to simplify those functions by not having to write the parameter name for every parameter on every function. Also would help if the parameters change, etc.

Comment: If the parameters are based on parameters in an external routine, then aren't you already hard-coding information that may change by defining the functions yourself? In a case like this it would probably be better to generate the source code itself, via [T4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx) for example.

Comment: Actually, T4 templates might be useful. I'll look into them, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get parameter names/values procedurally from the currently executing function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405230/can-i-get-parameter-names-values-procedurally-from-the-currently-executing-funct)

Comment: here is a simular question for C#:
[link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939508/get-value-of-c-sharp-dynamic-property-via-string

Answer (score 0):

The following method will return the property (given the property name) value:

```
Public Function GetPropertyValue(propertyName As String) As Object

        Dim pi As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = Me.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)

        If (Not pi Is Nothing) And pi.CanRead Then
            Return pi.GetValue(Me, Nothing)
        End If

        Dim a As Type() = Nothing
        Dim mi As System.Reflection.MethodInfo = Me.GetType().GetMethod("Get" + propertyName, a)

        If Not mi Is Nothing Then
            Return mi.Invoke(Me, Nothing)
        End If

        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

If you want to print 'Xyzzy' then

```
Console.WriteLine(Test("Xyzzy"))
' Should print: Xyzzy
Function Test(ByVal x as String)
  Return x                 
End Function
```