# How to get method parameter in an array?

Tags: c#

Imagine in a class you got this Method:

```
float Do(int a_,string b_){}
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
float Do(int a_, string b_)
{
  var params = GetParamsListOfCurrentMethod(); //params is an array that contains (a_ and b_)
}
```

Can someone help ?

Why should I want to do thet ?

Imagine you got an Interface:

```
public Interface ITrucMuch
{
 float Do(int a_,string b_);
 // And much more fct
}
```

And a lot of classes implementing that interface

And a special class  that also implement interface:

```
public class MasterTrucMuch : ITrucMuch
{
  public floatDo(int a_, string b_) 
  {
    ITrucMuch tm = Factory.GetOptimizedTrucMuch(); // This'll return an optimized trucMuch based on some state
    if(tm != null)
    {
      return tm.Do(a_,b_);
    }
    else
    {
      logSomeInfo(...);
    }

    //do the fallback method
  }
```

As the interface constains a lot of method and as the first lien of all method are always the same (checking if there is a better interface that the current instance and if so call the same method on the instance) I try to make a method of it.

Thx

Comment: Have you looked a .NET Reflection to see the Method and its parameters @ runtime?

Comment: Why? If you explain the reason for wanting to do so there may be a better solution.

Comment: Do you want the values or the names? Or both. By any chance are you looking to log them?

Comment: +1 to @Yuck and Ray's comment. Its unclear if you want the values arranged in an array, or if you want the parameter names passed to the method.

Comment: I edited to be a little bit more clear (I hope)

Answer (score 13):

You could do something like this:

```
var parameters = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters();
foreach (ParameterInfo parameter in parameters)
{
    //..
}
```

Have a look at the [ParameterInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

```
var params = GetParamsListOfCurrentMethod();
```

params is a C# keyword so it can't be used as a variable name as above.

Here's a link on how to use the params keyword
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx

And some example code pulled form the article.

```
public static void UseParams(params int[] list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(list[i] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: of course, it would be very simple if i could change the signature of the method... But I can't.

Comment: @PitMing Sorry I mis-understood your question. What is your goal exactly?

Comment: If one absolutely must: `var @params = GetParamsListOfCurrentMethod();`

Answer (score 0):

you can write your function with dynamic parameter like this:

```
    protected void Do(params object[] list)
    {
            if (list.Length < 2)
                return;

            int a_=(int)list[0];
            string b_=list[1].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Reflection .NET to get the parameter names for the method.

[Using reflection to get method name and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471693/using-reflection-to-get-method-name-and-parameters)

or

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it. If you want the param values, and this is the method you need to work with, what about simple doing

```
protected void Do(int a_, string b_)
{
  var paramValues = new object[]{a_, b_};
}
```

Do you want a more generic answer? Then you are duplicating questions [Can I get parameter names/values procedurally from the currently executing function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405230/can-i-get-parameter-names-values-procedurally-from-the-currently-executing-funct) and [How to get parameter value from StackTrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820630/how-to-get-parameter-value-from-stacktrace)
And you can't, basically.